Custom grain doesn't appear to be available on first execution even though reactor is performing a saltutil.sync_all?
I have developed a custom grain which simply enumerates the available network interfaces and categorise them as either internal or external based on their IPv4 address. This information is then used to make configuration decisions for certain pieces of software. For example, if a host has an internal interface syslog-ng will be installed and configured to send it's logs to an internal syslog server, but if a host has no internal interfaces a SIEM agent is installed and logs are sent to a public SIEM sensor.
This works as expected on already deployed hosts, but fails on newly deployed hosts until highstate is executed a second time, even though reactor on the salt-master is configured to execute saltutil.sync_all as per https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/topics/reactor/index.html#minion-start-reactor
The salt master reactor is setup as follows...
Contents of /etc/salt/master.d/reactor.conf
reactor:
  - 'salt/minion/*/start':          # Match tag "salt/minion/*/start"
    - /srv/reactor/sync_all.sls     # Sync dynamic modules on first start to make custom grains available on first highstate https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/topics/reactor/index.html#minion-start-reactor
    - /srv/reactor/start.sls        # Things to do when a minion starts

Contents of /srv/reactor/sync_all.sls
sync_grains:
  local.saltutil.sync_all:
    - tgt: {{ data['id'] }}

Contents of /srv/reactor/start.sls
highstate_run:
  local.state.apply:
    - tgt: {{ data['id'] }}

Relevant output from salt-run state.event pretty=true on the salt-master, once the key has been authorized manually.
salt/job/20240917193208454856/ret/debian-180  {
    "_stamp": "2024-09-17T19:32:10.633109",
    "cmd": "_return",
    "fun": "saltutil.sync_all",
    "fun_args": [],
    "id": "debian-180",
    "jid": "20240917193208454856",
    "retcode": 0,
    "return": {
        "beacons": [],
        "clouds": [],
        "engines": [],
        "executors": [],
        "grains": [
            "grains.abc_interfaces",
        ],
        "log_handlers": [],
        "matchers": [],
        "modules": [],
        "output": [],
        "proxymodules": [],
        "renderers": [],
        "returners": [],
        "sdb": [],
        "serializers": [],
        "states": [],
        "thorium": [],
        "utils": []
    },
    "success": true,
    "user": "salt"
}

salt/job/20240917193208435339/ret/debian-180  {
    "_stamp": "2024-09-17T19:32:12.431952",
    "cmd": "_return",
    "fun": "state.apply",
    "fun_args": [],
    "id": "debian-180",
    "jid": "20240917193208435339",
    "out": "highstate",
    "retcode": 1,
    "return": [
        "Rendering SLS 'base:linux/core-software/siem_agent' failed: Jinja variable 'str object' has no attribute 'external'; line 3\n\n---\n# IF host has a public interface then install SIEM agent\n\n{% if salt['grains.get']('abc_interfaces')['external']['count'] >= 1 %}    <====
==================\n\ninstall_siemagent_repo:\n  pkgrepo.managed:\n  - aptkey: False\n  - humanname: SIEM agent Repo\n[...]\n---",
        "Rendering SLS 'base:linux/core-software/syslog-ng' failed: Jinja variable 'str object' has no attribute 'internal'; line 1\n\n---\n{% if salt['grains.get']('abc_interfaces')['internal']['count'] >= 1 %}    <======================\ninstall_syslog-ng:\n  pkg.insta
lled:\n    - name: syslog-ng\n\nconfig_syslog-ng1:\n[...]\n---"        
    ],
    "success": false,
    "user": "salt"
}

Relevant output from /var/log/salt/minion on the salt-minion (with log_level: info set), once the key has been authorized manually.
2024-09-17 20:32:08,584 [salt.minion      :1739][INFO    ][1432] User salt Executing command state.apply with jid 20240917193208435339
2024-09-17 20:32:08,653 [salt.minion      :1739][INFO    ][1432] User salt Executing command saltutil.sync_all with jid 20240917193208454856

Interestingly, I've just noticed while creating this question that the saltutil.sync_all is in the salt-master logs before the state.apply, but in the salt-minion logs the saltutil.sync_all.
Is it possible the reactor states are being executed in parallel and I've got a race condition?

This might be related to https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/65027
